# Does AVRO schema also get encoded in the binary part?

Tags: serialization, deserialization, avro

An Avro file contains the schema in plain text followed by the data in binary format. I'd like to know whether the schema (or some part of it) also exists in the binary part? I got a hunch that the schema (or just the field names) also get coded in the binary part because when I make some changes in the plain schema part of an AVRO file I get an error message when exporting the schema using the Avro-tool.jar .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the binary encoding is used, the whole file is using a binary format.

The file starts with a 4 bytes header, then a map containing some metadata immediately follows. This map contains a "avro.schema" entry. The value of this entry is the schema stored as a string. After the map you will find your data.

If you edit the schema manually, read change its size, then length prefix stored just before this string will be incoherent and the file is corrupted.

See [Binary encoding specification](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.7/spec.html#binary_encoding) to learn how various types are binary encoded.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, and I quite sure that is should not be done. But for fun, lets try to edit the schema in place.

For this example I will use the `weather.avro` file from the avro's source tree:

`$ java -jar avro-tools-1.8.0.jar  getmeta weather-orig.avro
  avro.codec    null
  avro.schema     {"type":"record","name":"Weather","namespace":"test","fields":[{"name":"station","type":"string"},{"name":"time","type":"long"},{"name":"temp","type":"int"}],"doc":"A weather reading."}`

`$ java -jar avro-tools-1.8.0.jar  getschema weather-orig.avro 
  {
    "type" : "record", "name" : "Weather", "namespace" : "test", "doc" : "A weather reading.",
    "fields" : [ 
       {"name" : "station", "type" : "string"}, 
       {"name" : "time", "type" : "long"}, 
       {"name" : "temp", "type" : "int"} 
    ]
  }`

`$ java -jar /avro-tools-1.8.0.jar  tojson weather-orig.avro 
  {"station":"011990-99999","time":-619524000000,"temp":0}
  {"station":"011990-99999","time":-619506000000,"temp":22}
  {"station":"011990-99999","time":-619484400000,"temp":-11}
  {"station":"012650-99999","time":-655531200000,"temp":111}
  {"station":"012650-99999","time":-655509600000,"temp":78}`

OK. This is our source file. Plain simple, two metadata entries and the schema defines three fields. Now, we will try to understand how things are stored in binary and how we can edit the file to change the rename `station` int `station-id`.

`$ hexdump weather-orig.avro  -n 256 -C
00000000  4f 62 6a 01 04 14 61 76  72 6f 2e 63 6f 64 65 63  |Obj...avro.codec|
00000010  08 6e 75 6c 6c 16 61 76  72 6f 2e 73 63 68 65 6d  |.null.avro.schem|
00000020  61 f2 02 7b 22 74 79 70  65 22 3a 22 72 65 63 6f  |a..{"type":"reco|
00000030  72 64 22 2c 22 6e 61 6d  65 22 3a 22 57 65 61 74  |rd","name":"Weat|
00000040  68 65 72 22 2c 22 6e 61  6d 65 73 70 61 63 65 22  |her","namespace"|
00000050  3a 22 74 65 73 74 22 2c  22 66 69 65 6c 64 73 22  |:"test","fields"|
00000060  3a 5b 7b 22 6e 61 6d 65  22 3a 22 73 74 61 74 69  |:[{"name":"stati|
00000070  6f 6e 22 2c 22 74 79 70  65 22 3a 22 73 74 72 69  |on","type":"stri|
00000080  6e 67 22 7d 2c 7b 22 6e  61 6d 65 22 3a 22 74 69  |ng"},{"name":"ti|
00000090  6d 65 22 2c 22 74 79 70  65 22 3a 22 6c 6f 6e 67  |me","type":"long|
000000a0  22 7d 2c 7b 22 6e 61 6d  65 22 3a 22 74 65 6d 70  |"},{"name":"temp|
000000b0  22 2c 22 74 79 70 65 22  3a 22 69 6e 74 22 7d 5d  |","type":"int"}]|
000000c0  2c 22 64 6f 63 22 3a 22  41 20 77 65 61 74 68 65  |,"doc":"A weathe|
000000d0  72 20 72 65 61 64 69 6e  67 2e 22 7d 00 b0 81 b3  |r reading."}....|
000000e0  c4 0a 0c f6 62 fa c9 38  fd 7e 52 00 a7 0a cc 01  |....b..8.~R.....|
000000f0  18 30 31 31 39 39 30 2d  39 39 39 39 39 ff a3 90  |.011990-99999...|`

- First four bytes, `4f 62 6a 01`, are the header
- The next thing is a `long` describing the size of the first block of the "*metadata*" map. `long` are encoded using variable-length zig-zag coding, so here `04` means 2 which coherent with the output of `getmeta`. (remember to read the Avro specification to know how various data type are encoded)
- Just after you will find the first key of the map. A key is a string and a string is prefixed by its length in bytes. Here `0x14` means 10 bytes which is the length of "`avro.codec`" when encoded in UTF-8.
- You can then skip the next 10 bytes and go to the next element. Etc. You can advance until you spot the `avro.schema` part.
- Just after this string is the length of the map value (which is a string since it is our schema). That is what you want to modify. We are renaming `station` into `station-id` so you want to add 3 to the current length, so `f2 02` should now be `f8 02` (remember variable length zig zag coding ?).
- You can now update the schema string to add "-id"
- Enjoy

`java -jar /home/cmathieu/Sources/avro-trunk/lang/java/tools/target/avro-tools-1.8.0-SNAPSHOT.jar  tojson weather.avro 
{"station-id":"011990-99999","time":-619524000000,"temp":0}
{"station-id":"011990-99999","time":-619506000000,"temp":22}
{"station-id":"011990-99999","time":-619484400000,"temp":-11}
{"station-id":"012650-99999","time":-655531200000,"temp":111}
{"station-id":"012650-99999","time":-655509600000,"temp":78}`

But as I said, you most likely don't want to do that.

Comment: That's `hexdump -n 256 -C weather-orig.avro` on Mac OS X.